# php how to cache function output until script ends other than define

Tags: php, function, optimization

Lets say I have a function that I want to call few times, and during 1 run, the output cannot be other for same user, for instance, let's say this function checks if user is an admin, looks it up in database and finishes in miliseconds.

Now when I call this function one or two times, its fine. If I do this multiple times (for instance at least 100 times per page load) it is noticably too slow and wastefull. Caching its output for one script run seems to be great idea.

If solution exists, the best would be one that works both for classes and stand alone functions. In my case this is standalone function.

Is there any other way than using define?

```
function readStuff(){
  if(defined("readStuffAlreadyDone"))
    return readStuffAlreadyDone;
  //....
  define("readStuffAlreadyDone",$output);
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Is this a function of a class? Can you provide some more context for your question?

Comment: its not function of class in this particular scenario or for my use, but for others it might be. its just function without any other "accessories", added with require_once.

Comment: I believe is more to it. A simple use case is that you can build a authentication mechanism available in the whole project. Retrieve the user details once in the authentication class/variable/array . And then check that entity and not retrieve it from the datasource each time you want to know the user's rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use classes:

```
class StuffReader {

    protected $stuff;

    public function getStuff()
    {
        if (!$this->stuff) {
            $this->stuff = ...; // reading stuff
        }
        return $this->stuff;
    }

}

$stuffReader = new StuffReader();
$stuffReader->getStuff();
$stuffReader->getStuff();
$stuffReader->getStuff();
$stuffReader->getStuff();
$stuffReader->getStuff();
```

Or static function variables:

```
function readStuff()
{
    return 'some stuff';
}

function getStuff()
{
    static $stuff = readStuff();
    return $stuff;
}

getStuff();
getStuff();
getStuff();
getStuff();
getStuff();
```

Comment: okay, this is something definitely better than define, but it will work only for classes, so it is partialy answered my question. Though your solution for classes is better than my solutions for standalone functions.  Im looking if there is any way to do same that you done here, and what I done in my code that is works for both. I can accept answer "nope, thats not possible". this is also legit answer.

Comment: so I clicked accept answer too fast.. appearently it crashes for me (cant use expressions for static)